# Not Able to connect to Hive Using Java Code

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am able to connect to hive using beeline. But not able to connect through JDBC. I am getting version information Related Error.

Error: ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore.)

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Register driver and create driver instance

    Class.forName(driverName);
    // get connection

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");
    System.out.println("Connection: " + con.getCatalog());
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE userdb");
    System.out.println("Database userdb created successfully.");

    con.close();
}
```

Below is the pom details.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
     <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
     <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Please Help

Comment: which version of hadoop you are using?

Comment: hadoop version 3.2.0.. Cli and beeline is working fine..But if I connect through jdbc then I am getting this error.

Comment: Make sure that JDBC driver and HMS versions match, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool#HiveSchemaTool-MetastoreSchemaVerification